# Find a work item using an attached hyperlink

Tags: c#, tfs

I create work items through the TFS api.

```
var type = project.WorkItemTypes["Bug"];
var workItem = new WorkItem(type)
{
    History = "Created by OneTrueError incident #" + dto.OneTrueErrorIncidentId,
    Title = dto.Title,
    Description = dto.StackTrace,
};
workItem.Fields["Activity"].Value = dto.Activity;
workItem.Fields["Repro Steps"].Value = dto.StepsToReproduce;
workItem.Links.Add(new Hyperlink(someBaseUri + "/issue/" + dto.OneTrueErrorIncidentId));
workItem.Save();
```

At a later point I want to be able to fetch a specific work item by querying on a Hyperlink that I attached when creating the work item.

I can't figure out how to write that query. All examples I've found regarding links are for links to other work items or TFS resources. I have had no luck trying to modify those examples.

So how can I find a specific workitem using WIQL and a specific Hyperlink.Location?

Comment: I suggest you to use some structured tag in order to do filtering: you can query tags but not links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not able to directly use *hyperlink url* info in WIQL. You could only use **Hyperlink Count**  field which returns the number of hyperlinks that are defined for the work item.

```
Reference Name=System.HyperLinkCount, Data type=Integer
```

As a workaround you may have to [get a list of worktiems with links](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/work-items#with-links-and-attachments) and go through all returned info to match the url that your attached when creating the work item. Then get the work item.

Comment: Is that some other way to attach references to external resources without having to modify the process template? i.e. are there some kind of field which can be used for that? so that I can query on it later?

Comment: @jgauffin Afraid there is no this kind of field.(Here is the [Work item field index](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/guidance/work-item-field)) We usually use link and attachment to achieve this. If you don't have many work items with hyperlink, you could use `Hyperlink Count = 1` [Query based on link or attachment counts](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/track/linking-attachments#query-based-on-link-or-attachment-counts)